# Ember acceptance test fails with error You have turned on testing mode, which disabled the run-loop's autorun

Tags: ember.js, acceptance-testing, ember-qunit

I am writing acceptance test for which I get the following error 
Uncaught Error: Assertion Failed: You have turned on testing mode, which disabled the run-loop's autorun. You will need to wrap any code with asynchronous side-effects in a run

This error is caused when I use an Ember add on component (maintained by other teams). 
As I understand this error is caused due to not wrapping any asynchronous code in run loops, I tried to wrap all my code in runloops but nothing works.

As I do not have control over the external addon, is there a way to overcome this by changing something in my code or test setup?

I cannot post the code here but my test is as simple as

```
    visit('/someurl')
        andthen(()=>{
        //assert something
        })
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `run` here:

```
import { run } from '@ember/runloop';

test('my test', async function(assert) {
  await visit('/someurl');
  run(()=>{
    //assert something
  });
});
```

Here's a good article about the [Ember-run loop](https://medium.com/square-corner-blog/the-ember-run-loop-and-asynchronous-testing-c03326181623)

Comment: I tried moving assert statements in runloop but facing same error. When I put breakpoint, the error is coming even before going to assertion